# Find the critical points of this function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+xy+{1\over x}+{1\over y}$

I keep getting this:

$-12x^9+19x^6+11x^2-2=0$

Comment: How are you getting this? And why is it problematic?

Comment: Are you saying it's problematic because it doesn't involve $ y $ while your initial equation was symmetric between $ x $ and $ y $?

Comment: I get this when I try to solve $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$ for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Can you show your algebra explicitly?

Comment: $f_x=2x+y-{1\over x^2}$
Setting $f_x=0$,
$y={1\over x^2}-2x^2$
$f_y=2y+x-{1\over y^2}$
Setting $f_y=0$ and substituting $y={1\over x^2}-2x^2$,
I get,
$-12x^9+19x^6+11x^2-2=0$